# Conservation of charge (covariant equation) in Dirac's "GTR" (Ch 23, p. 43)

Tags: general-relativity, conservation-laws, maxwell-equations

In Dirac's "General Theory of Relativity", chapter 23 on the electromagnetic field, page 43, he derives Maxwell's equations in covariant form, $F_{\mu\nu:\sigma} + F_{\nu\sigma:\mu} + F_{\sigma\mu:\nu} =0$ and $F^{\mu\nu}_{\quad:\nu} = 4\pi J^\mu$.

He closes the chapter by saying that it is "immediately" [obvious] that $\left( F^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g} \right)_{,\mu\nu} = 0$. Here $g$ is the determinant of the metric tensor: $g = \text{det}[g_{\alpha\beta}]$. This leads to a conservation law for charge $\left(J^\mu\sqrt{-g} \right)_{,\mu} = 0$.

**Question: why is $\left( F^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g} \right)_{,\mu\nu} = 0$ obvious?**

Comment: Hint: Check the $\mu\nu$ antisymmetry.

Comment: Oh, for God's sake. Thank you.

Comment: @KhunChang But you didn't ask, why bother for an extra $\sqrt{-g}$ if only symmetry of indices is deciding factor here?

Comment: @KP99: I don't understand exactly what you're saying. $g$ is just a number.

Comment: No it's not necessarily just a number, and it depends on your choice of coordinates. Ex: minkowski metric, schawrzschild metric in spherical coordinates etc. If $g$ was always just a number, then $\nabla^2 f=\partial^2 f$ , which is not true

Comment: For a particular choice of coordinates, $g$ is a scalar and the double sum vanishes owing to antisymmetry of $F$.

Comment: My point was that $(F^{\mu\nu})_{,\mu\nu}=0$ just as $(F^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g})_{,\mu\nu}=0$ due to antisymmetry of F. But do you know the significance for the extra $\sqrt{-g}$ factor? Why this particular factor?

Comment: I see, now your question is clear. I did not include all the background in my question, since it was not necessary. Dirac shows that for any antisymmetric tensor, $F^{\mu\nu}_{\quad:\nu}\sqrt{-g} = \left(F^{\mu\nu}\sqrt{-g}\right)_{,v}$. This follows from $\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\mu}\sqrt{-g} = \left(\sqrt{-g}\right)_{,v}$. 

The $\sqrt{-g}$ factor enters in the first place via the change of variable formula. Hence, the conservation law for charge $J^\mu_{\,\, ,\mu}=0$ is modified by the $\sqrt{-g}$ factor.